# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to - \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k! }$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to - \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k! }$$ is

A)$-\infty$

B) $\infty$

C)$0$

D)$1/e$

I tried $\sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k! } \lt e^x$ Taking limit i got the answer to be less than zero. However the answer given is B. Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Check your inequality again. It doesn't hold for every value of $x$. You just have a polynomial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an even-degree polynomial. The largest power of $x$ eventually dominates, and $x^{1000} \to +\infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But $x^{999}$ tends to $-\infty$ as $x$ tends to $-\infty$. In other words we cannot subtract or add infinity. Can you please explain why other powers of $x$ donot dominate the sum. Thanks.

Comment: Let $P(x) = x^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_kx^k$ be a polynomial. Let $x>A=\max\{1,\max_{k} |a_k|\}$. Then $$ \frac{P(x)}{x^n} = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_k}{x^{n-k}}.  $$ Since every power in the sum is negative, it can be made as close to zero as we like by taking $|x|$ large enough. Hence it can be made less in modulus than $1/2$, say, so we have the bound $|P(x)-x^n| < \frac{1}{2}|x|^n$. This means that $P(x)$ and $x^n$ have the same sign for $|x|$ sufficiently large, and also $|P(x)| > \frac{1}{2}|x|^n$, so $|P(x)|$ diverges. Hence it diverges in the same direction as $x^n$.

Comment: or considering the limit of the last two terms:
$\lim_\limits{x\to+\infty} \left(\frac{x^{1000}}{1000!}-\frac{x^{999}}{999!}\right)=\lim_\limits{x\to+\infty} \frac{x^{999}}{1000!}\left(x-1000\right)=+\infty,$ since $x>1000.$